My Collision isn't working the way I want it to
I am trying to make a game slimier to Minecraft, where there is a world of blocks, and a player that can walk, jump, and place blocks. Lately, I've been struggling to get collision detection between the player and the blocks in the world. Here is a summarized script with my code:


class CapsuleCollider {
  constructor(start, end, radius) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  // Calculate the center of the capsule
  getCenter() {
    return this.start.clone().add(this.end).multiplyScalar(0.5);
  }

  // Get the end points of the capsule
  getEndPoints() {
    return {
      start: this.start,
      end: this.end
    };
  }
}


class BlockOctree {
  constructor(bounds, depth = 0) {
    this.bounds = bounds;
    this.depth = depth;
    this.blocks = [];
    this.children = [];
  }

  insert(block) {
    if (this.children.length) {
      const index = this.getOctantIndex(block.position);
      this.children[index].insert(block);
      return;
    }

    this.blocks.push(block);
    if (this.blocks.length > MAX_BLOCKS && this.depth < MAX_DEPTH) {
      this.subdivide();
    }
  }

  subdivide() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      const newBounds = this.calculateChildBounds(i);
      this.children[i] = new BlockOctree(newBounds, this.depth + 1);
    }

    while (this.blocks.length) {
      const block = this.blocks.pop();
      const index = this.getOctantIndex(block.position);
      this.children[index].insert(block);
    }
  }

  getOctantIndex(position) {
    // Determine the octant index for a given positionK
  }

  calculateChildBounds(index) {
    // Calculate the boundaries of each child octant
  }



  checkCollisions(playerCollider) {
    const capsuleCollider = new CapsuleCollider(
      playerCollider.start,
      playerCollider.end,
      playerCollider.radius
    );

    const start = capsuleCollider.start;
    const end = capsuleCollider.end;
    const radius = capsuleCollider.radius;

    let collision = null;

    blockOctree.blocks.forEach((blockData) => {
      const blockBoundingBox = blockData.boundingBox.clone();

      // Check multiple points along the capsule's length
      const pointsToCheck = 10; // Increase for more precision
      for (let i = 0; i <= pointsToCheck; i++) {
        const point = start.clone().lerp(end, i / pointsToCheck);
        const closestPoint = blockBoundingBox.clampPoint(point, new THREE.Vector3());
        const distance = closestPoint.distanceTo(point);

        if (distance < radius) {
          const collisionVector = closestPoint.clone().sub(point);
          const depth = radius - distance;
          collision = {
            normal: collisionVector.normalize(),
            depth: depth,
            block: blockData.block,
            blockPosition: blockData.position,
            collisionPoint: point
          };

          // Respond to the first collision detected
          const pushBack = collision.normal.multiplyScalar(collision.depth);

          // Adjust player position by the pushBack vector
          playerCollider.start.add(pushBack);
          playerCollider.end.add(pushBack);

          // Break after handling the first collision to avoid over-adjustment
          break;
        }
      }

      // Break if a collision is already found
      if (collision) return;
    });

    if (collision) {
      const {
        collisionPoint,
        normal,
        depth
      } = collision;

      // Normalize player's position based on the collision point
      const adjustment = normal.multiplyScalar(depth);
      playerCollider.start.add(adjustment);
      playerCollider.end.add(adjustment);

      return collision;
    }

    return false;
  }
}



Note: The code in the snippet is for show, so this isn't running properly.
The problem is is that once the player hits one of the blocks, the player pops up a bit. It also feels like the center of the capsule is the thing that is colliding with the blocks, and not the whole capsule (but I could be wrong).
This might also be missing a few things, so if you need clarification, let me know.

Do any of you guys know how to fix my current code or know how to do it better?

I would start by fixing the Gif in your post, it is not working for me, and then removing all unnecessary code from your snippet only keeping collision code.

You can't see the gif? Alright. I'll describe what is going on in it (while also keeping the gif for those who can see it.).
I guess I can remove most of the code too.

@Charanor I forgot to at you. How does this look?

It's hard to know what could be wrong without being able to debug it locally but this part seems incorrect: // Break if a collision is already found       if (collision) return;. You are inside of a lambda function inside the forEach call so this return doesn't return from the collision function, it returns from the forEach function (which does nothing it's at the end already). What you need to do is convert the forEach into a normal for loop: blockOctree.blocks.forEach becomes for (const blockData of blockOctree.blocks) { ... }. I would start by fixing that and see where that gets you.

@Charanor That changed quite a lot. It gave me a different perspective on what was going on. Now I have some minor issues that I'll need to fix, but with what you recommended, I am finally seeing most of the causes of my issues. Thank you very much for your advice. I've been stuck on this for almost two months, and now the development for this game seems like it is starting to kick off.
